# A simple example of finding default gateway by getadaptersinfo

Tags: c++

I searched but it`s difficult to understand.

I just need a function that gets adapter name & returns its default gateway (windows & linux). That`s it.

Thanks.
Ya Ali.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495619/how-to-get-all-network-interface-name-and-information-in-c

Comment: Hello dear John.
I need DG in both windows & linux OS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738733/how-to-get-internal-ip-external-ip-and-default-gateway-for-upnp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513704/linux-c-find-default-gateway-ip-address-rather-than-parsing-proc-filesystem